# Adding "nofollow" to existing rel attribute

Tags: html, rel

I´m trying to add `nofollow` to a link with an existing `rel` attribute that triggers an `iframe` popup.

Here is the link I am trying to alter:

```
<a class="modal" rel="{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 700, y: 550}}" 
title="Email" href="/myurl.html">link text...</a>
```

The question is, how do I add `nofollow` to the `rel` attribute without messing up the popup?

I have tried this, but it comprimizes the popup release:

```
<a class="modal" rel="nofollow {handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 700, y: 550}}" 
title="Email" href="/myurl.html">link text...</a>
```

Comment: This is more of a problem with your popup plugin.

Comment: `data-*`attributes, man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try having the links with `rel="nofollow"` so search engines can read it, and then you can change that value onclick. like this

```
<a id="mylink" rel="nofollow" onclick="return changerel(this);" href="#">link</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function changerel(el)
{
    var myreplace = "{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 700, y: 550}}";

    alert('rel before:'+el.rel)

    el.setAttribute("rel", myreplace);

    alert('rel after:'+el.rel);

    if (el.rel != myreplace)
    {
         el.onclick();   
    }
}
</script>
```

see it in action here
http://jsfiddle.net/5Basb/4/

Comment: It’s `nofollow`, not `no-follow`.

Comment: This worked perfectly for what I was trying to do. Now the question is whether Google bots etc. will comply to the nofollow attribute or will they render the javascript and disregard the nofollow?

Answer (score 1):

Having a JavaScript object in the `rel` attribute is non-standard, so is `nofollow`. However, the `nofollow` attribute value would comply with [valid link types](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/links.html#adef-rel). What library or environment uses the information in your `rel` attribute? You could store it in a [`data` attribute](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/global-attributes.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes), so the `rel` can be used for its original intent.